# add to a dataframe a index generate with date_range with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a big file with many data. The first line represents the x-coordinate of measurement stations; the second the y-coordinate and the third the z-coordinate.
From the fourth to the end I have all measurements data. The data are from 1/1/1956 00:00:00 to '31/12/2013 23:00:00.

The file looks like:

```
626323;616720;616288;611860;622375;626285;636292
5188431;5181393;5173583;5165895;5152605;5164800;5164801
1915;1499;1310;1235;1907;874;698;
-9999;0,-9999;1,2,3.4,4
-9999;0,-9999;0;20;38;4.7
```

I would like to add an index as dateindex in order to work properly with date.
As a consequence, I am facing two problem.

The first one is to add an index as date to the original dataframe. Consequently, I have generated the indexes as:

```
index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1956 00:00:00',end='31/12/2013 23:00:00', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

After that I have read the original dataframe as:

```
dfs = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=';',index_col=None, header = 0)
```

Now arrive the second problem linked with the first one: how can I add the indexes without considering the first three lines, which however I can not erase because I need them in order to apply some calculations?

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: I think you should clarify further the formatting of the data file, it has both `;` and `,` so reading it as is didn't work for me anyway.

Comment: you are right. sorry. I correct immediately. It's a standard csv file with formatting ";". I have edit the answer.

Comment: You have two seperate types of data, the first three lines should be removed into their own DataFrame, or a separate type of python object (tuple maybe?). Another option would be to convert then to columns in your dataframe.

Comment: I am starting to read some documentation. What about MultiIndex?